# Is it possible to output more than 8 channels with Web Audio API?

Tags: macos, audio, web-audio-api

I'm experimenting with Web Audio API to control playback of interactive music in a multi channel setup. So far I've managed to direct the sound of up to 8 oscillators to 8 different channels on my 12 channel sound card, but as soon as I try to use more than 8 channels, suddenly all channels gets muted. After a lot of research I also notice that `audioContext.currentTime` gets stuck on a value near zero.

This is my result from MAC OSX 10.8.5
Google Chrome Version 39.0.2171.27 beta (64-bit)
and Version 40.0.2192.0 canary (64-bit).

Safari does not allow me to address more than 2 channels
FireFox finds my 12 channels with `audioContext.destination.maxChannelCount` but keeps on routing my sound to channel 1 & 2 no matter if I try to connect the oscillator to a higher number with `gain.connect(channelMerger, 0, i)`.

Has anyone come across anything similar? Are there workarounds?

Here is the code:

```
var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var audioContext = new AudioContext();
var maxChannelCount = audioContext.destination.maxChannelCount;

// if set to max 8 it works fine in Chrome, but this line
// breaks the audio if the sound card has got more than 8 channels
audioContext.destination.channelCount = maxChannelCount; 
audioContext.destination.channelCountMode = "explicit";
audioContext.destination.channelInterpretation = "discrete";

var channelMerger = audioContext.createChannelMerger(maxChannelCount);
channelMerger.channelCount = 1;
channelMerger.channelCountMode = "explicit";
channelMerger.channelInterpretation = "discrete";
channelMerger.connect(audioContext.destination);

for(var i = 0; i < maxChannelCount; i++){
    var oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
    oscillator.connect(channelMerger, 0, i);
    oscillator.start(0);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Record audio on web, preset: 16000Hz 16bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969304/record-audio-on-web-preset-16000hz-16bit)

Answer (score 1):

We haven't implemented multi-channel support in Firefox. It's been prioritized and will happen at some point in the next two quarter, an then released shortly after.