# Record audio on web, preset: 16000Hz 16bit

Tags: javascript, audio, record, web-audio-api

```
function floatTo16BitPCM(output, offset, input){
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++, offset+=2){
    var s = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, input[i]));
    output.setInt16(offset, s < 0 ? s * 0x8000 : s * 0x7FFF, true);
  }
}

function writeString(view, offset, string){
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    view.setUint8(offset + i, string.charCodeAt(i));
  }
}

function encodeWAV(samples){
  var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + samples.length * 2);
  var view = new DataView(buffer);

  /* RIFF identifier */
  writeString(view, 0, 'RIFF');
  /* RIFF chunk length */
  view.setUint32(4, 36 + samples.length * 2, true);
  /* RIFF type */
  writeString(view, 8, 'WAVE');
  /* format chunk identifier */
  writeString(view, 12, 'fmt ');
  /* format chunk length */
  view.setUint32(16, 16, true);
  /* sample format (raw) */
  view.setUint16(20, 1, true);
  /* channel count */
  view.setUint16(22, 2, true);
  /* sample rate */
  view.setUint32(24, sampleRate, true);
  /* byte rate (sample rate * block align) */
  view.setUint32(28, sampleRate * 4, true);
  /* block align (channel count * bytes per sample) */
  view.setUint16(32, 4, true);
  /* bits per sample */
  view.setUint16(34, 16, true);
  /* data chunk identifier */
  writeString(view, 36, 'data');
  /* data chunk length */
  view.setUint32(40, samples.length * 2, true);

  floatTo16BitPCM(view, 44, samples);

  return view;
}
```

Hi, I am using this source code to record audio for my school exam. It records audio in 44100Hz and 16bit. I want to change recording settings to record  audio in 16000Hz and 16bit.
I tried modify 44 in function encodeWAV to 16 but it didn't work.

```
function encodeWAV(samples){
  var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + samples.length * 2);
  var view = new DataView(buffer)
```

Also I have tried to change floadRToBitPCM. I tried to change 44 to 16 but it also didn't work.

```
floatTo16BitPCM(view, 44, samples);
```

Can you help me with this issue?? I don't know how to modify this source code.

Comment: Where is your sampleRate variable being set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe you can control sample rate using Web Audio API ... it picks up the system default sample rate which is defined outside the browser ... of course subsequent to recording, you can programmatically alter your audio to resample to any sample rate ...   Most audio players can only play media of standard sample rates ... being able to render an off sample rate of 16 kHz might be more challenging than resampling from 44.1 to 16 kHz

Answer (score 9):

**Edit:**

Another option(much better one IMO) is just to go for the HTML's MediaRecorder and record in `.ogg` format, [demo](https://mido22.github.io/MediaRecorder-sample/), and it's [git repo](https://github.com/Mido22/MediaRecorder-sample)

---

I am assuming that you are using [this](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) as the source,  and like jaket said, the line `floatTo16BitPCM(view, 44, samples);` has nothing to do with sampling rate...

if you want to resample the data, you have modify this:

```
function exportWAV(type){
    var buffers = [];
    for (var channel = 0; channel < numChannels; channel++){
        buffers.push(mergeBuffers(recBuffers[channel], recLength));
    }
    if (numChannels === 2){
        var interleaved = interleave(buffers[0], buffers[1]);
    } else {
        var interleaved = buffers[0];
    }
    var dataview = encodeWAV(interleaved);
    var audioBlob = new Blob([dataview], { type: type });
    this.postMessage(audioBlob);
}
```

into this:

```
function exportWAV(type, desiredSamplingRate){
    var buffers = [];
    for (var channel = 0; channel < numChannels; channel++){
        var buffer = mergeBuffers(recBuffers[channel], recLength);
        buffer = interpolateArray(buffer, desiredSamplingRate, sampleRate);
        buffers.push(buffer);
    }
    sampleRate = desiredSamplingRate;
    if (numChannels === 2){
        var interleaved = interleave(buffers[0], buffers[1]);
    } else {
        var interleaved = buffers[0];
    }
    var dataview = encodeWAV(interleaved);
    var audioBlob = new Blob([dataview], { type: type });
    this.postMessage(audioBlob);
}
```

code for re-sampling data,

```
// for changing the sampling rate, data,
function interpolateArray(data, newSampleRate, oldSampleRate) {
    var fitCount = Math.round(data.length*(newSampleRate/oldSampleRate));
    var newData = new Array();
    var springFactor = new Number((data.length - 1) / (fitCount - 1));
    newData[0] = data[0]; // for new allocation
    for ( var i = 1; i < fitCount - 1; i++) {
    var tmp = i * springFactor;
    var before = new Number(Math.floor(tmp)).toFixed();
    var after = new Number(Math.ceil(tmp)).toFixed();
    var atPoint = tmp - before;
    newData[i] = this.linearInterpolate(data[before], data[after], atPoint);
    }
    newData[fitCount - 1] = data[data.length - 1]; // for new allocation
    return newData;
};
function linearInterpolate(before, after, atPoint) {
    return before + (after - before) * atPoint;
};
```

**Edit:** if you not going to change it too much, you can just hard code it as

```
function exportWAV(type){
    var buffers = [], desiredSamplingRate = 16000;
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I use this source code from github.com. I have tried modified the code  according to you instruction as you wrote above. Everything seems work good, but when I download recorded sound to PC it can't be open. There is an error while opening that the audio is not supported format. It seems that audio is damaged or recorded in format that isn't supported in PC.

Comment: check this code, https://github.com/Mido22/tmp1, for me, it works on both `firefox` and `chrome` in linux env...

Comment: Note that using a linear interpolation to downsample significantly without a sinc filter ("brickwall" low-pass filter) is likely to cause some severe aliasing issues in high-frequency content.

Comment: @cwilso I think the OP is trying to record human voice for some project, so I guessed that we dont need to worry about the high frequency bit...

Comment: @mido22 I have tried implement your source code. It works, so it records voice, also I can download recorded sound to my PC and play it. But there is a problem: recording  sound is slowed down. Recorded voice is slower and much more deeper than it should be. Recording is damaged.

Comment: @mido22 that doesn't matter - in fact, it makes it MORE concerning, because there is a lot of HF noise in human voice.  If you don't filter out the noise BEFORE downsampling, it can cause bad aliasing noise.  It will still *WORK*, but may have bad artifacting.

Comment: @Nikolaus - you'll need to change the two occurrences of "sampleRate" in encodeWAV() to desiredSampleRate, also.

Comment: @cwilso any suggestions for how to implement a fast filter would be helpful concerning, because I am using similar code in my other projects also, have very basic idea about speech processing...

Answer (score 3):

You are modifying the wrong field. A wave file is a header followed by the data. The wave header is *typically* 44 bytes long. The value of `44` you are seeing in the sample code is related to that and not to `44100`.

Somewhere in code you have not posted, `sampleRate` is defined to be 44100. You need to track down that definition and change it to 16000. Depending on the rest of your code and the source of the samples it may not be quite that simple though. For example, if samples are being recorded from a device and the device has been configured to record at 44100 then simply marking the saved waveform as 16000 is not going to have the desired effect. It's just going to make playback 2.75x too slow aka the Barry White effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the init function like this, here you can overcome the default browser sample rate to 16000 and also the channels indicating the mono/stereo we can change that one also ,
 if it is mono it will be 1 , other wise two .

```
 function init(config) {
            //sampleRate = config.sampleRate;
            sampleRate = 16000;
            debugger;
            //numChannels = config.numChannels;
            numChannels = 1;
            initBuffers();
        }
```