# RecordRTC with custom sample rate records silence

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webrtc, getusermedia

I'm trying to use RecordRTC.js to record audio from a microphone and upload it to a nancyfx server.

For testing purposes, I'm just trying to upload the audio stream and save it to a wav file. My requirement is, however, that the stream is saved in 16 bits at 22050Hz.

The problem is, when I record the file using standard configuration (without recordRtcOptions) , I can upload the file and save it. When I specify the sample rate in recordrtc the output file is just silence.

The relevant part of the code is inside an angularJS service as follows:

```
app.service('AudioService', ['$window', '$http', function($window, $http) {

    var recordRtcOptions = {
        'sample-rate' : 22050
    };

    navigator.getUserMedia = (
        $window.navigator.getUserMedia ||
        $window.navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
        $window.navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
        $window.navigator.msGetUserMedia)

    var _recordRTC = {};
    navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false }, function (stream) {
        console.log('starting to initialize getUserMedia');
        console.log(recordRtcOptions);

        _recordRTC = RecordRTC(stream, recordRtcOptions);    

        console.log('Finished initializing getUserMedia');
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('Error initializing media stream: ' + error);  
    });

    var instance = {};

    instance.startRecording = function() {
        console.log('starting to record...');
        console.log('sample rate: ' + _recordRTC.sampleRate);
        _recordRTC.startRecording();
    };

    instance.stopRecording = function(uploadPath) {

        console.log('sample rate: ' + _recordRTC.sampleRate);


        _recordRTC.stopRecording(function(audioVideoMURL) {
            console.log('stopped recording...');
            console.log('recordrtc stop sample rate: ' + _recordRTC.sampleRate);

            $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : uploadPath,
                data : _recordRTC.getBlob()
            }).success(function(data) {
                console.log('POST /audio Success');

            }).error(function() {
                console.log('POST /audio error'); 
            });
        });

    };

    return instance;

}]);
```

Any idea on what might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to understand the problem you need to look into `RecordRTC.js`:

- first the function `mergeProps` copies the config you provided.
- the function `reformatProps` converts "sample-rate" into property "sampleRate".
- `StereoRecorder` is used for recording, which internally uses `StereoAudioRecorder` which is essentially similar as [mattdiamond/Recorderjs](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs).

when you look into that, it does not take `sampleRate` as input, but determines it from these line

```
var Recorder = function(source, cfg){
    ...
    this.context = source.context;
    ...
        sampleRate: this.context.sampleRate, // --> this is the right way to provide sampleRate
```

and in RecordRTC,

```
var sampleRate = typeof config.sampleRate !== 'undefined' ? config.sampleRate : context.sampleRate || 44100;
```

long story short, if you notice, here too when sample rate is not provided, it takes `context.sampleRate` which is sample rate provided by the microphone, so just changing the sample rate in config is not sufficient, because all that would do is alter the samplerate value that is written on to the `.wav` file( can check the function `mergeLeftRightBuffers` for confirmation) but the data would have still been recorded on the original sample rate.

If you really want to modify the sampleRate, you can look at [Record audio on web, preset: 16000Hz 16bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969304/record-audio-on-web-preset-16000hz-16bit/28977136#28977136)

Comment: I'll accept your answer since it answers the question. For future reference, I'll try to record in the default format and process the audio in the server (low pass filtering and ressampling).

Comment: yea, I agree, what I am doing is mere interpolation and that is not the right way.