# Is there way to play multiple audio tracks at once in mp4 container

Tags: javascript, html

I have simple mp4 container and want to play all audio tracks in it. The audio/video element plays only the first one.

I couldn't get to audio tracks of the container.

```
<video id="video" src="somevideo.mp4"></video>
<script>
var video = document.getElementById("video");

for (var i = 0; i < video.audioTracks.length; i += 1) {
  video.audioTracks[i].enabled = true;
}
</script>
```

Is it possible to play all tracks?

Comment: Consider that `audioTracks` is not supported in all browsers. What browser are you using?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I'm using latest Chrome. I don't actually care about what browser to pick up, I just need to know if there is possible way to do it

Comment: See note 2 [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=audiotracks). Have you already tried that?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, thanks a lot. I did turn on Experimental Web Platform features in Chrome in now got tracks visible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the WebAudio API to do this, although it will only allow you to playback 32 channels.

The flow is:

- attach the source (ie URL) to an audio element
- create a ChannelSplitterNode
- create a ChannelMergerNode
- obtain an AudioDestinationNode
- connect these up in the order above, except you chose which outputs of the splitter node to connect to the merger node.

Some useful references:

- [Is it possible to output more than 8 channels with Web Audio API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434235/is-it-possible-to-output-more-than-8-channels-with-web-audio-api)
- https://github.com/thomasdeppisch/MultichannelAudioCodecBrowserTester